# Not able to solve the media query issue (responsive design)

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

I tried the following code for making my page responsive, but still the elements are moving out. Can anyone lease have a look at it and help me out?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    .top-bar-section ul {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  .widget-area {
    display: none;
  }
  .stat {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .clients-style-2 .slides li .client-logo {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  #clients .slides li .client-logo {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  #icategories li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Ref url: http://7drives.in/dsq/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a YouTube video in an iframe, and that iframe has a hard coded width of 500px, so this will be a problem on narrower viewports.

[CSS Tricks has one solution to thi](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/)s, jQuery below. There are other solutions for responsive iframes, I like that this is a simple drop fix which doesn't require any changes to your HTML, and also that it resizes both the width and the height of your video.

Hope this helps!

```
// By Chris Coyier & tweaked by Mathias Bynens

$(function() {

    // Find all YouTube videos
    var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),

        // The element that is fluid width
        $fluidEl = $("body");

    // Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
    $allVideos.each(function() {

        $(this)
            .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

            // and remove the hard coded width/height
            .removeAttr('height')
            .removeAttr('width');

    });

    // When the window is resized
    // (You'll probably want to debounce this)
    $(window).resize(function() {

        var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

        // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
        $allVideos.each(function() {

            var $el = $(this);
            $el
                .width(newWidth)
                .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

        });

    // Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
    }).resize();

});
```